# Add a Total Row after each Unique CustomerName

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a 'Total' row after each Unique CustomerName. I have tried ROLLUP and it does not seem to work properly because of the amount of fields i am trying to group by. An example of what i am looking for would pseudo be

(
FlavorName('Total'), 2016Sales (Sum of total sales), 2017Sales (Sum of total sales), 2016TotalPounds (Sum of total pounds), 2017TotalPounds (Sum of total pounds))

Please find my current code below.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT        CustName AS CustomerName, ItemKey AS CICode, Description AS FlavorName, CASE WHEN InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND 
                                                      '2016-12-31' THEN SUM(LineNet) ELSE 0 END AS [2016TotalSales], CASE WHEN InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND getdate() THEN SUM(LineNet)
                                                       ELSE 0 END AS [2017TotalSales], CASE WHEN InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' THEN ROUND(SUM(QtyOrd), 2) 
                                                      ELSE 0 END AS [2016TotalPounds], CASE WHEN InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND getdate() THEN ROUND(SUM(QtyOrd), 2) 
                                                      ELSE 0 END AS [2017TotalPounds], BasePrice, SUBSTRING(CAST(InvoiceDate AS nvarchar(50)), 8, 5) AS year, UOM
                             FROM            dbo.ABC
                             GROUP BY CustName, ItemKey, Description, BasePrice, InvoiceDate, UOM)
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT CustomerName, CASE WHEN CICode IS NULL THEN 'ALL' ELSE CICode END AS CICode, CASE WHEN BasePrice IS NULL

                              THEN 'TOTALS' ELSE FlavorName END AS FlavorName, SUM([2016TotalSales]) AS [2016Sales], SUM([2017TotalSales]) AS [2017Sales], SUM([2016TotalPounds]) 
                              AS [2016TotalPounds], ROUND(SUM([2017TotalPounds]), 2) AS [2017TotalPounds], UOM, ISNULL(ROUND((SUM([2017TotalPounds]) - SUM([2016TotalPounds])) 
                              / NULLIF (SUM([2016TotalPounds]), 0) * 100, 2), 100) AS [%Change], BasePrice
     FROM            cte AS cte_1
     GROUP BY CustomerName, CICode, FlavorName, BasePrice, UOM
     HAVING         (SUM([2016TotalSales]) + SUM([2017TotalSales]) > 0)
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQLServer. Please tag only the DBMS you are really use.

Comment: i am sorry about that. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `GROUPING SETS`:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (CustomerName, CICode, FlavorName, BasePrice, UOM), (CustomerName) )
```

You may have to play with `ORDER BY` to get the results in the particular order that you want.

Comment: even with messing with the Group by order it is not returning the total properly.